# double data type in mysql to store null when the form fields submitted are blank

Tags: html, mysql, forms, null, double

I have a form that I am using to update a mysql database using PHP and html. I set my data type in mysql as double (3,1). The problem is when  I submit the data to the database I get a 0 where I had put nothing on the form input fields; What I want is these columns to be null.

I don't know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Let us see your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sName = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['sName']);
$datetime1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['datetime1']);
$rain = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['rain']);
$max = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['max']);
$min = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['min']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO rain(sName, datetime, rain, min, max) VALUES ('$sName',    '$datetime1', '$rain','$max','$min')";
```

part of my html code

```
<p>
                    <label for="max">Maximum Temp:</label>
                    <input type="number" min="10.0" max="55.0"   name="max" id="max" value="">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="min">Minimum Temp:</label>
                    <input type="number" min="-3.0" max="40.0"  name="min" id="min"value="">
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you can use this :

```
<form method="post" action="traitement.php">
    <label for="data">Data :</label>
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

PHP :

```
if(empty($_POST['data'])) {
    //insert null in your database
}
else {
    //insert data
}
```